# Mapping PostgreSQL XML type to byte[] field of entity bean

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa, hibernate-mapping

We need to map an xml field in postgres table to Java entity field of type byte[].
We are using Hibernate for ORM.

Please let us know best method to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by implementing org.hibernate.usertype.UserType interface.

Then annotated the entity as given below:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="xml")
@Type(type="app.domain.XmlType")
private String contentXml;
```

Comment: Is there any public/library implementation of the generic XmlType available?